# How to start with this code to find Definite Integral of this equation using Javascript?

Tags: javascript

I got the following Function:

```
 f(x) = log(sin(x)) + 1
```

And I want to calculate the integral from x=0.5 to x=2.5. For that I defined these variables:

```
a = 0.5
b = 2.5
n = 10
```

The answer I got using the Calculator is

```
integral_0.5^2.5 (log(sin(x)) + 1)  = 1.6171
```

I have to find three answers using n = 10 equal sized intervals for the function f(x)
using:

- the trapezoidal method:

area of segment equals base times the average of the height at the two end points of the segment.

```
  h = (b-a)/n
  A = (f(x)+f(x+h))*(h/2)
```

- Simpson's 1/3 rule

  h = (b-a)/(2*n)
     A = (f(x)+4*f(x+h)+f(x+h+h))*(h/3)
- Simpson's 3/8 rule

  h = (b-a)/(3*n)
    A = (f(x)+3*f(x+h)+3*f(x+h+h)+f(x+h+h+h))*(3*h/8)

Comment: Please add the code you wrote. If this is a sole mathematical question it should rather be asked in math overflow.

Comment: <html><body><script>
var f1 = function(x){
            return Math.log(Math.sin(x)) + 1;
                       }
        var integral = function(f,a,b){
            var area = 0;
            var dx = 0.001;
            for(let x = a; x < b; x += dx){
                area += dx*f(x);
            }
            return area;
        }
        document.write((integral(f1,0.5,2.5)));
</html></body></script>